# Удалить все буквы между определенными символами

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Нужно удалить все что лежит между определенным маркером ( К примеру: "%" ) и символом "\n" (Т.е новая строка)

```rb
def solution(input, markers)

end

solution("dsfaas% fdfd\nFOO !F\n BAR", ["%", "!"])
```

На выходе должно получится что-то типа
"dsfaas FOO BAR"

Comment: *На выходе должно получится что-то типа "dsfaas FOO BAR"* А пробел между 'dsfaas' и 'FOO' каким ветром надуло-то?

Comment: А каким должен быть результат для `"dsfaas%dsfaas% fdfd\nFOO !F\n BAR"`? Варианты: `"dsfaasFOO  BAR"` и `"dsfaas%dsfaasFOO  BAR"`.

Comment: Это не пробел, а новая cтрока, \n стоит же перед FOO и BAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый примитивный вариант:

```ruby
def solution(str, markers)
  str.gsub(/[#{markers.join}].*\n/, '')
end
```

Но тут надо помнить, что символы `-`, `[`,
и `]` использовать надо крайне осторожно, ибо они могут быть
неверно интерпретированы в регулярном выражении.

Answer (score 1):

```
puts "sfaas% fdfd\nFOO !F\n BAR".gsub(/[\%\!][^\n]*\n/,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input.split(markers[0])[1].
      split(markers[1])[0]
```